# pythonAnywhere AttributeError : module 'pytube' has no attribute 'YouTube'

Tags: pip, python-3.6, pythonanywhere, pytube

I am making a project with Django and pytube in python 3.6, but when I run the code below in my python anywhere project, I get this error:
`AttributeError : module 'pytube' has no attribute 'YouTube'`.

```
import pytube

url = input()
yt = pytube.YouTube(url)
```

This probably is because there are multiple packages named pytube, and I think that I installed the wrong one. Which one do I have to install? And should I than use `pip` or `pip3`?

I already tried uninstalling pytube and reinstalling (also via the GitHub link which you can find from other people who are having issues with this: `git+https://github.com/nficano/pytube.git`)

Comment: Check if your web app is using the same version of Python that you used for installing pytube (or, if you're using venv -- if you actually installed pytube in it). I could succesfully install pytube and download a video on my PythonAnywhere account.

Comment: @caseneuve okay, thanks ! That gives me hope. but how did you install pytube? and did you use python 3.6.9 ? and `pip` or `pip3` and `pytube` or `pytube3` ? There are a lot of versions...

Comment: There are multiple versions of Python installed; if you run "python3.8", you'll get Python 3.8, if you run "python3.7", you'll get 3.7, and so on. They all have their own associated versions of pip installed, eg. "pip3.8".  The commands "python" and "pip" are aliased to "python2.7" and "pip2.7" respectively.

Comment: Also, take a look at https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/InstallingNewModules/

Comment: @TijmenMeijer I installed it in a virtuals env for Python 3.8 and 3.6.

Comment: @caseneuve how did you install it? Did you `cd` to `venv` and than `pip instal pytube` or their GitHub clone link?

Comment: You need to the venv to be activated when you install packages for it. If you use `mkvirtualenv` command the venv would be automatically activated after creation, or if you start a new console etc. you can use `workon <venv-name>` command. Once venv is active you run `pip install` (Python version for pip will default to the venv Python).

Comment: @caseneuve okay THANKS! That worked, but how to download the video from the website? ```stream = yt.streams.first().download()``` doesn't download anything...

Comment: was their an error? if this isn't an official youtube api, then PythonAnywhere would have blocked it for free accounts btw.